# Is there a correlation between armed security and casualties of people working in security?

Tags: protests, police, public-safety

I am working for a private security company. We currently have a debate about whether carrying firearms would improve our safety or make our job even more dangerous. Is anyone aware of any study showing a correlation between security being armed with firearms and being injured more often?

Comment: This report looks at workplace injuries and homicides of security workers but does not break out between armed and unarmed security workers. https://www.bls.gov/iif/oshwc/osh/os/osar0009.pdf It doesn't answer the question but does provide a universe of information and given the small sample size explains why it may be hard to find statistically significant datasets. The FBI has looked at bank security (arming is bad). https://www.revealnews.org/article/fbi-bank-robbery-data-shows-armed-guards-increase-risk-of-violence/

Comment: This appears to be a question about workplace safety, not about politics. It could be on-topic on workplace stackexchange if framed accordingly. I will give it an edit to make it on-topic there and migrate it.

Comment: @Philipp There seems to be some relation between this question and the actual political view that disarming the police (usually patrol police) has a positive effect on society (and possibly on the police themselves). UK, Norway, New Zealand, are some of the examples where this is already happening (and apparently with success). I recommend reopening this question. The description can be slightly changed to include a more macroscopic view on the subject if it's currently too specific.

Comment: Moreover, is there a correlation between armed security and casualties of people *not* working in security?

Comment: As asked it is looking for advice in a certain workplace situation. While political decisions may provide context, It is not about political processes.

Comment: @JamesK, The leading sentence of the Q  provides background, but does not appear to be an appeal for personal advice.  Rather it asks how uniform armament impacts worker safety in *general*.  Since [worker safety is political](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_labor_law#Health_and_safety),  so is this question.